# How to Implement Auto Image Slider inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, androidimageslider

I'm Using the Following Library in my project to Auto Slide images. It works fine inside Activities but when it comes to Fragment it throws a null pointer exception when the context is passed As `getContext();`or `getActivity();` instead of `this;`. I stuck with that now.
Please Help.

Library name: [Link To Library](https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider)

My Code Inside Fragment:

```
SliderView sliderView = view.findViewById(R.id.ImageSlider);

SliderImageAdapter adapter = new SliderImageAdapter(getContext());
adapter.setCount(5);

sliderView.setSliderAdapter(adapter);

sliderView.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimations.SLIDE); //set indicator animation by using SliderLayout.IndicatorAnimations. :WORM or THIN_WORM or COLOR or DROP or FILL or NONE or SCALE or SCALE_DOWN or SLIDE and SWAP!!
sliderView.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.CUBEINROTATIONTRANSFORMATION);
sliderView.setAutoCycleDirection(SliderView.AUTO_CYCLE_DIRECTION_BACK_AND_FORTH);
sliderView.setIndicatorSelectedColor(Color.WHITE);
sliderView.setIndicatorUnselectedColor(Color.GRAY);
sliderView.startAutoCycle();
```

My Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.coderedinnovations.allioservices, PID: 7955
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView.setSliderAdapter(com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderViewAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.coderedinnovations.allioservices.AllioMain.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:53)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1188)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1433)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7987)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3521)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:226)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:206)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:178)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:102)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2222)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7772)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
```

Layout Code:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="14dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView
        android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:sliderAnimationDuration="600"
        app:sliderAutoCycleDirection="back_and_forth"
        app:sliderAutoCycleEnabled="true"
        app:sliderIndicatorAnimationDuration="600"
        app:sliderIndicatorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        app:sliderIndicatorMargin="15dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorOrientation="horizontal"
        app:sliderIndicatorPadding="3dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorRadius="0.5dp"
        app:sliderIndicatorSelectedColor="#5A5A5A"
        app:sliderIndicatorUnselectedColor="#FFF"
        app:sliderScrollTimeInSec="1"
        app:sliderStartAutoCycle="true" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

There is no problem with my adapter and its working for the other activity that I had.

Comment: Can you please post the logcat? You should see the crash log in your logcat.

Comment: I just Posted my Logcat have a Look. Hope You'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the logcat error logs, it is difficult to understand what is the problem here. However, I thought I should put some suggestions so that you could investigate the problem yourself.

You might consider initializing your adapter from the `Fragment` as follows.

```
SliderImageAdapter adapter = new SliderImageAdapter(getActivity());
```

Also, please check if the layout that you are using has the `ImageSlider` attribute. If you do not have that layout id in your fragment's layout that you are trying to inflate, it should have a null pointer exception as well.

The adapter is looking fine IMHO.

**Update**

From the logcat, it looks like the layout that you are using for your `Fragment` does not have the `ImageSlider` and hence it could not initialize the `sliderView`.

From the layout that you posted, seems like the layout id is `imageSlider`, not `ImageSlider`. The layout ids are case-sensitive.

Hence you should have the following line modified as follows.

```
view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
```

Comment: I tried getActivity(); and getContext(); but none of them worked for me.

Comment: I can't get you can you elucidate

Comment: What is the layout that you are using for your fragment?

Comment: I have the same issue. I get a Nullpointerexception even though I am referencing the correct SliderView...

Comment: @CodeREDInnovations did you find a solution to the problem?